# Is it possible to integrate apache spark with jasper using the spark's jdbc driver?

Tags: hadoop, jasper-reports, apache-spark, spark-streaming

We want to use apache spark for real time analytics ? We currently use hive/MR for data crunching and mysqlsql to store the aggregated results , and jasper reports for analytics ? This approach is far from ideal because of scalability issues with mysql. We are in the process of exploring apache spark to run on top of hdfs or cassandra , only problem is if there is a way for spark to integrate with jasper server? If not what are other UI options to use with spark ?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer and thought of sharing , if you use hive metastore with spark you could persist RDDs as hive Tables , once you have done that any client which talks hive:jdbc2 protocol can run hive or sql like queries using spark's execution engine.
 These are the steps  -
 1) Configure spark to use mysql as metastore database.
 2) copy hive-site.xml in spark conf directory , pointing to mysql database.
 3) start thrift service , you can do this using $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-thrift.sh , if successfully started it listens on port 10000.
 4) test this using a client like beeline , which is under $SPARK_HOME/bin directory.
 5) From beeline use this url - !connect hive:jdbc2://localhost 10000 (no username or password)
 6) run any hive create or select query.
 7) If it runs, congrats !! , use the same url as above from jasper (!connect hive:jdbc2://localhost 10000 , replace localhost with ip) using hive:jdbc2 .